# How to make my hangman game can find more than 2 double letter?

Tags: python

I had a problem in my hangman program finding more than 2 double letter word.

EX:if i had `aabc` or `aaabc` in my guess wordlist, then i guess `a` `b` `c` is won't tell me i get right. But if i had `abc` in guess wordlist, and i guess `a` `b` `c` , then i get right.

Here what's my code are:

```
while keep_playing:
    wordlist=["butterfly","tree","circumstances","jinrikisha"]
    word=choice(wordlist)
    word_len=len(word)
    guesses=word_len * ['_']
    max_incorrect=7
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"
    letters_tried=""
    number_guesses=0
    letters_correct=0
    incorrect_guesses=0
    print_game_rules(max_incorrect,word_len)
    while (incorrect_guesses != max_incorrect) and (letters_correct != word_len):
        clues()
        letter=get_letter()
        if len(letter)==1 and letter.isalpha():
            if letters_tried.find(letter) != -1:
                print "You already picked", letter
            else:
                letters_tried = letters_tried + letter
                first_index=word.find(letter)
                if  first_index == -1:
                    incorrect_guesses= incorrect_guesses +1
                    print "The",letter,"is not the mystery word."
                else:
                    print"The",letter,"is in the mystery word."
                    letters_correct=letters_correct+1
                    for i in range(word_len):
                        if letter == word[i]:
                            guesses[i] = letter
        else:
            print "Please guess a single letter in the alphabet."
```

See how my wordlist all had more than 2 double letter, and never tell me i guess right, even i guessed all letter.
I know once the word len letter is more than 2 (as double letter)is won't get it right, but how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The end-condition is incorrect because `letters_correct` is *only incremented by one* each time (even if the letter occurred multiple times).

I would change the [victory] end-condition to "when there are no _'s in `guesses`" which means that all the _'s have been replaced which means... (also make sure to take the input phrase "hello world" [and similar] into account when generating `guesses`, if it matters).

Happy homeworking.

---

Bonus points for making the program more "modular": a trivial change is to make the main loop (with victory condition test) call a method which prompts for a letter and then updates the display.